# No Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header Is Present Or Working With Cross Origin Request In ASP.NET Web API

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, https, cors

I want to build a monitoring website. As a tech stack I use frontend React and backend ASP.NET.
I have access to the database via an API Controller and it is displayed correctly, but I cannot see the data in my frontend.
I get the error:

> No Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header Is Present Or Working With Cross Origin Request In ASP.NET Web API..

I implemented CORS in the Program.cs and allowed access and the error still appears.

```
global using webapi.Models;

var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<PhdevContext>();

// Add CORS configuration
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                      policy =>
                      {
                          policy.WithOrigins("https://localhost:7036")
                              .AllowAnyHeader()
                              .AllowAnyMethod();
                      });
});

// services.AddResponseCaching();

builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

// Use CORS
app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Comment: `.WithOrigins("https://localhost:7036")` - 1) what is the address you are running the frontend localy (I assume you are testing your local setup) 2) better move this to configuration and read it from there.

Comment: The CORS middleware should be on top of the authorization middleware. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#middleware-order